# Leaflet full screen in Ionic-Cordova-Angular app

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I'm working on a mapping app using Ionic-Cordova-Angular and am trying to use Leaflet. My issue is that I can't get the Leaflet map to automatically fill the entire viewport.

I found the solution when using straight JS. You can use CSS to set the HTML and Body to a height of 100% and then set the map div to 100% as well. You can see this working in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wzfLs10a/

Unfortunately, the same solution does not work when I introduce Angular into the mix. Here's some sample code:

**Index.html**

```
<div id="map" ng-app="demoapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
```

**App.js**

```
angular.module("demoapp", ["controllers"]);

angular.module('controllers',[])

   .controller('MainCtrl',['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);            
        L.tileLayer('http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg', {
        attribution: 'Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/">MapQuest</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        subdomains: '1234'
    }).addTo($scope.map);

    }]);
```

**Style.css**

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;}
#map { height: 100%;}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3sv374Lz/. Note that if you change the height of the map div to a fixed value (400px for example), the map will display.

I am aware of the angular leaflet directive and am currently exploring that option as well, but it seems to me this really shouldn't be that difficult. Am I missing something simple? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a problem with angular itself or leaflet just an understanding of how the box model works.

https://jsfiddle.net/7k11k32m/

If you set some percentage height then the parent container of the one with a percentage must have a set height as well.  Since you introduced an extra div here without giving it a height then the map doesn't expand to fill the screen.

Updated your CSS (had a type on html too):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
[ng-app]{
    height:100%;
}
#map {
    height: 100%;
    /* Change 100% to 400px and the map will display    
}
```

As an aside I've personally found it easier to write my own directive for dealing with Google maps since their API is pretty nice and easy to work with and then I don't get the extra bloat from more third party stuff I'm not using, also this way no one to blame but me :).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer shaunhusain! I'm just getting my feet wet with html, JS, Angular and the like (coming from a corporate .NET background). There is a steep learning curve. Since I'm using Ionic, my map div is nested 6 or 7 tags deep: body > ion-nav-view > ion-view > ion-pane > ion-content > div > my map div. Setting the height of each of these elements to 100% works great! Not sure if I'm doing the correct way, but at least it is working for me now.

Comment: @dgboss yeah no problem, I come from a Flex/Java background so I know the feeling, being a fish out of water.  The box model is one of the worst things about working in browsers in my opinion, I used to really hate on JS but after using it for a while and learning Angular I'm pretty happy with that part.  Think once the css flex model for sizing things is in place in browsers that will make things better but for now we just have to deal.

Comment: this is not working anymore, and I am facing the same problem, the grey maps cause it can't download the tiles-
do u know how to fix it? Big thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you use ionic's content and view classes, you don't need to set each div to 100%.

I use leaflet in my ionic app with the following code:

```
<ion-view title="Map">
    <ion-content scroll="false" data-tap-disabled="true">
        <leaflet height="100%" width="100%"></leaflet>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Note that this uses the leaflet angular module https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive

Comment: It still does not work. Could you also show a simple controller for the same?